# Highlight words

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, highlight

Given a search query:

```
Sheeky's
```

The special characters are removed, and it's lowercased to:

```
sheekys
```

The same filters are applied to fields in the database I'm searching on.  This is so that a search for:

```
sheekys
```

Will return results for an item named:

```
Sheeky's Item
```

This is the filter:

```
public static string FilterSearchQuery(string query)
{
    return Regex.Replace(query, "[^0-9A-Za-z ]", "");
}
```

In the search results view, the matched words are highlighted like so:

`````````
public string HighlightText(string text)
{
    foreach (var word in HighlightWords)
    {
        var findWord = word.Trim();
        if (findWord.Length > 0)
        {
            var itemRegex = new Regex(findWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (var match in itemRegex.Matches(text))
            {
                text = text.Replace(match.ToString(),
                    "¬¬¬¬¬¬¬____¬¬¬¬¬¬" + match.ToString() + "````````____`````");
            }
        }
    }
    text = text.Replace("¬¬¬¬¬¬¬____¬¬¬¬¬¬", "<span class=\"highlighted\">");
    text = text.Replace("````````____`````", "</span>");

    return text.Replace("</span> <span class=\"highlighted\">", " ");
}
`````````

This highlights exact matches fine.  However, I'd like to extend it so that it highlights `Sheeky's` when the search term is `Sheeky`.  `HighlightWords` is a list of words searched for (without any filtering).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the current algorithm highlights only `Sheeky` in `Sheeky's` and you want it to highlight the whole word (as in, non-space characters)? You could perhaps use `new Regex(findWord + @"\S*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` instead?

Comment: sidenote: there is also a [`<mark>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag for highlighting.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, no? You'd also have to match any number of leading (@!~sheeky's) and trailing (sheeky's~$%) special characters as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
var itemRegex = new Regex(findWord + ".*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The above will match `Sheeky` plus anything after that.

Comment: If the search word is `sheekys` it wont match `sheeky's` but will match `sheekys'`

Comment: @TomGullen you need to provide some specific rules(like apostrophes), because if you are going to use regex to parse grammar it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finding the match in the original text, while ignoring non-letters. With some regex magic this works:

```
var content = "This is a long string with word's, words and Words"; // the text to search in

var tofind = "W'ords"; // the text to search for

// prepare search value: remove non-letters/digits, set to lowercase
tofind = Regex.Replace(tofind, @"\W", "").ToLower();

// create search regex: allow non-letter between the letters
var findregex = String.Join(@"\W*", tofind.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()));

// surround matches with a <mark> tag
var content2 = Regex.Replace(content, findregex, "<mark>$0</mark>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Result is

> `This is a long string with <mark>word's</mark>, <mark>words</mark> and <mark>Words</mark>`